# Text formating python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, f-string

I was wondering if I can use a simpler method to `print("{:<3} {:<30} {:<30}".format(x+1, cam, img))`.

I'm using `print(f"including a variable named var : {var}")`

instead of `print("including a variable named var :{}".format(var))`

But with the `f""` I can't find a method to put minimal margin unlike `"{:<30}".format(var)`

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the variable name before the `:` character to get the same result:

```
>>> name = "Tom"
>>> print(f"{name:>3} {name:>30}")

Tom                            Tom
```